# Java applet: monitor HTTP requests

Tags: java, jquery, json, applet

I am making a Java applet. I want to connect to a webpage and then the webpage will make a lot of get requests to an external server. How do I see the URL that the get requests are going to? And how do I see the responses?

Comment: An applet is a guest in a web page.  Like a guest in a guesthouse. Looking at HTTP traffic is the equivalent of a guest who eavesdrops on the communications of other guests (& management).  What benefit would I as potential end user get from this applet as opposed to running fiddler or equivalent software?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried proxies like membrane (http://www.membrane-soa.org/soap-monitor/) or fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) while testing ?